# How to get an array of method's parameters names and arguments from a base class?

Tags: php, magic-methods

So, basically, is there any way to do this pretty-way without using slow backtrace? Now i'm doing it like this:

```
class BaseTest {

    public function magic() {
        $args = func_get_args();
        $class = new ReflectionClass(get_called_class());
        $method = $class->getMethod($args[0]);
        $magic = array();
        foreach($method->getParameters() as $k => $parameter) {
            $magic[$parameter->getName()] = $args[$k];
        }
        return $magic;
    }


}
class Test extends BaseTest {

    public function testWithParams($param1, $param2) {
        return $this->magic(__FUNCTION__, $param1, $param2);
    }

}
$q = new Test();
var_dump($q->testWithParams(1,2));
```

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the above code?  Off the cuff, it looks like it'd grab what you want at least in terms of the magic() method.

Comment: Yeah, it's working fine, i'm just looking for any alternatives or optimizations. Like, no passing method name as an argument.